# What would be the DC to navigate through a heavy storm at sea?

Tags: dnd-5e, difficulty-class, travel

I am working on Seafaring Navigation DC checks. I have found the following DCs based on the Wilderness Navigation table on page 112 of the DMG and the following quote on page 117:

> As long as a ship is within sight of land, there is no chance of the vessel becoming lost.

but what I'm not sure about is what to do if they are in the middle of a heavy storm.

| Terrain | DC |
| --- | --- |
| Within Sight of Land | Assured (0) |
| Open Sea (Clear Skies, No Land) | Easy (10) |
| Open Sea (Overcast, No Land | Moderate (15) |

Page 118 of the DMG says:

> If weather conditions indicate both a strong wind and heavy rain, they combine to create a storm with high waves. A crew caught in a storm loses sight of all landmarks (unless there's a lighthouse or other bright feature), and ability checks made to navigate during the storm have disadvantage.

Should I just apply the Open Sea (Overcast, No Land) DC, or should it have it's own DC 20 while the storm is ongoing, to avoid becoming lost at sea?

Comment: What are you hoping to simulate, or what sorts of outcomes are you wanting to include? The quoted section suggests Disadvantage for navigation rolls during a storm, but it seems that doesn't accomplish what you are after.

Comment: That's more or less what I am trying to solve.  I get to that point and the next logical question is: Disadvantage against what DC?  The previous DC with view of the coastline was non-existent, being guaranteed success.  "Overcast, No Land" seems the most logical, but that doesn't much describe a storm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119446/discussion-between-bitfed-and-purple-monkey).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Upon further research I realized there is a "Storm DCs" table in Ghosts of Saltmarsh (p202).

#### Storm DCs

| DC | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Heavy Gale |
| 15 | Strong Storm |
| 20 | Typical Hurricane |
| 25 | Overwhelming Hurricane |

So it sounds reasonable to use the "Open Sea (Overcast)" DC of 15, which matches the Storm DC for "Strong Storm" at DC 15.